# Propagating Akka's PoisonPill messages

Tags: java, akka

Is Akka's PoisonPill is propagated to actor's children or children are simply being stopped without processing the rest of messages? Akka documentation isn't clear and there is an answer to similar question here in StackOverflow referring to old code stating that the children are being stopped, but doesn't make sense to me: why an actor is capable of gracefully processing the messages prior to poison pill, but its children are not.

Answer (score 1):

The `PoisonPill` is not propagated to the children. In other words, the children are stopped, not "poisoned." Once the parent processes the `PoisonPill`, it is stopped, and then its children are stopped. From the [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#actor-lifecycle):

> ...stopping a parent Actor will also recursively stop all the child Actors that this parent has created.

A naive approach would be to send a `PoisonPill` to the children before sending a `PoisonPill` to the parent. However, actor stopping occurs asynchronously, so there is no guarantee that the children will have processed the messages in their respective mailboxes--up to and including the `PoisonPill`--before they are stopped due to the parent's stopping.

To have better control over how an actor's children "die," take a look at this [pattern](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/howto.html#ordered-termination) mentioned in the documentation.